# Parse SQL Column into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to parse a sql column result into separate columns.  Here is an example of the column...

Detail - Column name

```
'TaxID changed from "111" to "333". Address1 changed from "542 Test St." to "333 Test St". State changed from "FL" to "DF". Zip changed from "11111" to "22222". Country changed from "US" to "MX". CurrencyCode changed from "usd" to "mxn". RFC Number changed from "" to "test". WarehouseID changed from "6" to "1". '
```

I need to take the old TAXID, new TAXID, old country, and new country and put them in separate columns.
The Detail column will always have TAXID and Country, however the challenging part is that they don't always have the rest of data that I listed above.  Sometimes it will contain city and other times it won't.  This means the order is always different.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You should fix the table design instead of having all the data together. The problem I see is no an easy field separator bacuse `"."` can also be part of the field data

Comment: Unfortunately the table design is out of my control.  I'm using sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

I would create a tsql proc, use a case statement.
Do a count of the double quotes. If there are 8 oairs, you know that you old and new values, only 4 pairs you only have new values.
Then using the double quotes as indexes for your substring, you can put the vales into the table.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with something that worked.

In case anyone else gets a situation like this again perhaps posting my code will help.

DECLARE @document varchar(350);

set @document = 'TaxID changed from "111" to "222"'

declare @FIRSTQUOTE int

declare @SECONDQUOTE int

declare @OLDTAXID nvarchar(40)

declare @firstlength int

declare @ThirdQuote int

declare @FourthQuote int

declare @secondlength int

declare @NewTAXID nvarchar(40)

declare @oneplussecondquote int

declare @oneplusthirdquote int

select @FirstQuote = CHARINDEX('"',@document)

set @FIRSTQUOTE = @FIRSTQUOTE + 1

select @SECONDQUOTE = CHARINDEX('"',@document,@FIRSTQUOTE)

set @firstlength = @SECONDQUOTE - @FIRSTQUOTE

select @OLDTAXID = SUBSTRING(@document,@FIRSTQUOTE,@firstlength)

set @oneplussecondquote = @SECONDQUOTE + 1

select @ThirdQuote = CHARINDEX('"',@document,@oneplussecondquote)

set @oneplusthirdquote = @ThirdQuote + 1

select @FourthQuote = CHARINDEX('"',@document,@oneplusthirdquote)

select @secondlength = @FourthQuote - @oneplusthirdquote

select @NewTAXID = SUBSTRING(@document,@oneplusthirdquote,@secondlength)

You can switch out the string for this: 'Country changed from "US" to "MX"'
And it would grab the old country and new country